# tkinter problem in displaying two frames using tkraise

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display two frames in a way such that one frame has a button to display the other frame and vice versa. I'm trying to use tkinter frame function of tkraise(). But they are getting simultaneously displayed over each other. Please you can ignore the import board file because it has some helper functions that I'm using to display some data on the GUI.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as st
from board import *

FONT = ("Helvetica", 20)
attributes = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title('DAS')
        self.geometry('500x325')

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        self.frames[0] = Display(container, self)
        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frames[1] = DataStored(container, self)
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.show_frame(1)

    def show_frame(self, frame):
        frame = self.frames[frame]
        frame.tkraise()

class Display(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller):
        super().__init__(container)

        name = tk.Label(self, text='Data Acquistion System', font=FONT)
        name.pack(fill='x')
        left_wrapper = tk.Frame(self)
        left_wrapper.pack(side='left')
        right_wrapper = tk.Frame(self)
        right_wrapper.pack(side='left')

        port_label = tk.Label(left_wrapper, text='Port:', font=FONT)
        port_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        port_option = tk.StringVar(left_wrapper, value='None')
        ports_availiable = get_arduino_ports()
        port_value = tk.OptionMenu(left_wrapper, port_option, *ports_availiable)
        port_value.grid(row=0, column=1)

        baud_label = tk.Label(left_wrapper, text='Baudrate:', font=FONT)
        baud_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        baud_value = tk.Entry(left_wrapper)
        baud_value.grid(row=1, column=1)
        baud_value.insert(0, 9600)

        connect_button = tk.Button(left_wrapper, text='Connect', command=lambda: connect_to_port(port_option.get(), baud_value.get()))
        connect_button.grid(row=2, column=1)
        playback_button = tk.Button(left_wrapper, text='Playback', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(1))
        playback_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

        data_display = st.ScrolledText(right_wrapper)
        data_display.pack()

class DataStored(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller):
        super().__init__(container)
        tk.Label(self, text='Playback Data').pack(fill=tk.X)
        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        top_frame.pack(fill=tk.X)
        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        bottom_frame.pack(fill=tk.X)
        
        canvas = st.ScrolledText(top_frame)
        canvas.pack()

        update = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Update', command=self.update_playback)
        update.grid(row=0, column=0)
        back = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Back', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(0))
        back.grid(row=0, column=1)

        
    def update_playback(self):
        with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
            data = file.read()
        self.data.insert(tk.END, data)
        self.data.config(state="disabled")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = App()
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple solution by changing the way in which you use your `show_frame` function:

```py
    def show_frame(self, frame_num):
        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[frame_num]
        frame.grid()
```

The reason `tkraise` does not work is that your two frames are of different sizes, if they were the same rise you would be entirely right with your code. Because they are of different sizes you can still see the bigger frame when looking at the smaller one.

`grid_remove` removes a frame from being loaded on the window, and then the following `grid` command places the frame back where it was before, removing any issues with overlap and such.

Answer (score 2):

As the two frames have different sizes, you need to add `sticky="nsew"` in `.grid(...)` to make both frames to occupy the available space:

```
        self.frames[0] = Display(container, self)
        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1] = DataStored(container, self)
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```